# how to pass parameters to implementation of HttpServer?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, httpserver

I have implemented com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer:

```
 HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8001), 0);
 server.createContext("/myserver", new myHttpHandler());
 server.createContext("/myserver/get", new GetHttpHandler());
```

I want to pass parameters to /myserver/get with the following url:

```
 http://localhost:8000/myserver/get?deviceid=ABB00122

 static class GetHttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

   public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {

 // how do I now access the deviceid?

   }
 }
```

How do I access the parameter deviceid I sent with my url in the handle method?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of `HttpExchange`? Start there.

Comment: It seems like I can access parameters via getAttribute, I tried String deviceid = (String)exchange.getAttribute("deviceid"); but get null as the value of deviceid.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The HttpServer class is very simple. If you want to access parameters passed in the URL (using the GET method) then you need to provide a method to extract them.

you get the full URL from:
httpExchange.getRequestURI().getQuery()

and then from this String you can get the details.

see http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-get-url-parameters-using-jdk-http-server.html  for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this type but it seems from the [HttpExchange doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/spi/http/HttpExchange.html) that attributes are not request parameters. The information is likely accessible via the [getQueryString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/spi/http/HttpExchange.html#getQueryString%28%29) method.

Comment: Okay.  If I switch to javax.xml.ws.spi.http.HttpExchange from com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange then how is javax.xml.ws.spi.http.HttpExchange used with com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer?  Should I also use com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler?

Comment: Okay, I have resolved the problem.  com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer should be used with com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange and com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler.  As for parsing the attributes sent, it's seems much more complicated since there is no getQueryString.